# Find the closed form solution to a geometric series not starting at 0

Tags: summation, geometric-series

I have the following geometric series:
$$
\sum_{i=k_0+1}^{k}{(b^\epsilon)^i}
$$

How can I find a closed-form solution for the following formula?
I know it's a geometric series, but in order to apply the formula, I need it to start from 0 and the $k_0+1$ is confusing me

Thanks

Comment: You could sum from zero to $k$ and then subtract the sum from zero to $k_0.$

Comment: or use the formula $a\left(\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right)$, where $a$ is the first term, $r$ is the ratio, and $n+1$ is the number of terms

Comment: Yes, I found the answer and will put it in answer for whoever needs it in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the following notation:
$$
\sum_{i=k_0+1}^{k}{(b^\epsilon)^i} = \sum_{i=k_0+1}^{k}{C^i} =S
$$
Therefore we can say that:
$$
S = C^{k_0+1} + C^{k_0+2} + ... + C^{k}\\
C*S = C^{k_0+2} + C^{k_0+3} + ... + C^{k+1}\\
C*S - S = S(C-1) = C^{k+1} - C^{k_0+1}\\
S = \frac{C^{k+1} - C^{k_0+1}}{C-1}
$$